# Riddle - who am I to gather such renown?

Tags: riddle, word

*I might be a city in one of the 'stans. 

I might be a river or more in Australia. 

I might have once bifurcated cleanly. 

I might have colleges named after me. 

I might be said to be covered in blood. 

What can I be to gather such renown?*

The answer is a single word.

Comment: You've told us the answer! It's "a single word" which, when used in a sentence, could mean any of those things! I'd answer with this but it isn't tagged lateral thinking lol.

Comment: http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/46/so-whats-our-actual-stance-on-riddles?cb=1

Comment: @JanDvorak What is the purpose behind linking this meta post?

Comment: @d'alar'cop how exactly do you define a _good_ riddle?

Comment: It may not be this question's fault, but it really doesn't look good when four of the related questions have a condescending title ("Are you clever enough") and a positive score...

Comment: @JanDvorak that's an issue we're still looking into. being crafted such that there is only one answer which satisfies _all_ clues is where we're upto. If you look at the top 2 answers of your posted meta link (the 2nd being my own) you'll see that it's not cut and dry but this author has a history of high quality posts. "are you clever enough?" is sort of a meme around here... it's only teasing, not condescending

Comment: @JanDvorak also just plopping down a meta post without any explanation is not good form, sir

Comment: A single answer doesn't guarantee the puzzle isn't terribly trivial.

Comment: I'd just forbid all riddles, actually. Claiming moderation is bad because there's work to do doesn't sound sound to me.

Comment: @JanDvorak triviality is in the eye of the beholder. there was only one answer posted... it wasn't yours or mine, it can't be all that trivial

Comment: @JanDvorak ok well that issue is not for me or you but the community to discuss... and it has done so at length (as it stands, in that linked meta post is that riddles are puzzles). for yourself, one good suggestion is to filter out riddles or post good quality questions yourself.

Comment: @JanDvorak I think using "condescending titles" is great! If my riddles are too difficult you can avoid my riddles easily by looking at the title. I won't hate you for that :) At the same time people who are clever enough can find me in no time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is:

> MARY

I might be a city in one of the 'stans.

> Mary is the capital city of Mary Province in Turkmenistan

I might be a river or more in Australia.

> The Mary River is a large river system in South East Queensland, Australia. [OP note: there are three Mary Rivers in different parts of Australia - [reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mary_River).)

I might have once bifurcated cleanly

> This is referring to the Virgin Mary, who gave birth after an 'immaculate conception'.

I might have colleges named after me.

> There are many colleges and universities named after Mary (Ex: St.Mary's College)

I might be said to be covered in blood.

> Reference to Bloody Mary

What can I be to gather such renown?

> Because she is the mother of 'Jesus Christ'.

Comment: You don't explain why this answer matches "bifurcated cleanly"...

Comment: "clean bifurcation" does probably refer to virgin birth. I think this is the right answer

Comment: Or it may be referring to the bifurcation between Mary Magdalene and Virgin Mary. Not sure.

Comment: Well done! 'Clean bifurcation' was meant to refer to virgin birth (and 'a river or more' means there are actually 3 Mary Rivers in Australia), but your answer already matches everything.

Comment: AeJey, I edited your answer slightly. Hope you don't mind!